# Uber webhook not working

Tags: webhooks, uber-api

Request receipt event is not firing after the ride is completed.I am initiating ride from ride request button. Scope of request receipt is given full access.

Does the web-hook is fired when ride is initiated from the ride request button?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the documenation provides an answer here, bolded the potentially relevant part: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/guides/webhooks

> "requests.receipt_ready Given that your application has access to the
>   request_receipt scope and has a valid OAuth authorization for a user,
>   Uber’s server will make a POST request to your application’s webhook
>   url when the Request Receipt status is available for Requests created
>   by your application a POST /requests. This will allow you to show your
>   user the details of their fare and how much they were charged as soon
>   as their Receipt is available. If the rider cancels after the grace
>   period, and they are charged, a receipt will be available showing that
>   charge.
>
> **The receipt endpoint will only provide receipts for ride requests
>   originating from your application. It is not currently possibly to
>   receive receipt data for all trips.**"